# Validate values in key value pair in a JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json

I need to validate a JSON against the available format. The sample JSON is as follows:

```
{
  "sno": "1",
  "project_name": "Abcd",    

  "contributors": [
    {
      "contributor_id": "1",
      "contributor_name": "Ron"
    },
    {
      "contributor_id": "2",
      "contributor_name": "Dan"
    }
    ],
    "office": [ "Vegas", "New York" ]
}
```

In the above example, I need to validate the JSON as follows:

- The value for *sno* must be a string.
- The value for *office* must be a valid array.
- The value for *contrbutors* must be a valid array with valid JSONs as members.

How can I parse the JSON and check if all the keys have valid values according to the above mentioned criteria?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem, why would someone write an api that changes the types of the json

Comment: If you only want to validate data types then you can simple deserialize it into class and check if it failed or not.

Comment: @TheGeneral I don't need to change the types of the json. I need to validate if the JSON is in the right format or not

Comment: That's not really what i was getting at. However, carry on

Comment: Do you just need to check if the json string is valid (i.e. you are able to deserialize it) or do you need to get some sort of list of validation errors?

Comment: BTW you have a typo in your json, shouldn't it be `contributors` instead of `contrbutors`?

Comment: @RuiJarimba I just need to check if the value of the key is in the right data type or not. contrbutors is a typo error. Rectified it

Comment: You can validate JSON against a [JSON Schema.](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema)

Comment: @Harry, I added custom function to check validation of data type in  my answer below view it might be it help you :)

Comment: @Harry, test `"sno": 1` means integer 1 with your accepted answer. and let me know if program goes to catch block or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need object like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
   public string sno { get; set; }
   public string project_name { get; set; }
   public List<Contrbutor> contrbutors { get; set; }
   public List<string> office { get; set; }
}

public class Contrbutor
{
   public string contributor_id { get; set; }
   public string contributor_name { get; set; }
}
```

Pars it via JsonConvert

```
try
{
    MyObject desObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(yourJsonStringHere);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //IF PARSE IS NOT SUCCESSFUL CATCH THE PARSE EX HERE
}
```

and if Parse is successful than validate "desObject" values.

Comment: if "sno": 1 means integer 1 not string 1 then your code does not goes to catch means there is no validation of datatype for string

Comment: Is it possible to get the name of the key in the catch block in which there is a data type mismatch ?

Answer (score 1):

You can build your custom function to check the data type of value of respective key in your json.

1) Parse your json to [**`JObject`**](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)

2) Map this `JObject` to your `SampleClass`.

3) Then by using [**`JTokenType`**](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JTokenType.htm) you can validate if particular value of respective key is of type `string` or `array` or `object`.

```
public string ValidateJson(string json)
{    
    JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

    SampleClass model = jObject.ToObject<SampleClass>();

    string response = string.Empty;

    foreach (var i in model.data)
    {
        switch (i.Key)
        {
            case "sno":
                if (i.Value.Type != JTokenType.String)
                    response = "SNo is not a string";
                break;

            case "project_name":
                if (i.Value.Type != JTokenType.String)
                    response = "Project name is not a string";
                break;

            case "contributors":
                if (i.Value.Type != JTokenType.Array)
                    response = "Contributors is not an array";
                break;

            case "office":
                if (i.Value.Type != JTokenType.Array)
                    response = "Office is not an array";
                break;
        }
    }

    return response;
}
```

Your `SampleClass` would be

```
class SampleClass
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JToken> data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Good one. I was trying to do it with a JsonTextReader but your solution is a bit simpler.